# Advice on testing an NG2 component that makes use of 3rd party JS library

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, leaflet

Looking for the right direction regarding testing the following component that uses a [3rd party JS library](http://leafletjs.com/) -

```
import * as Leaflet from "leaflet";

export class GeoFencingComponent {

    map: any;

    constructor() {
         this.map = Leaflet
            .map( "map" )
            .locate( {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                setView: true,
                maxZoom: 16
            } );
         Leaflet.tileLayer( "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" )
            .addTo( this.map );
    }
}
```

I have the following jasmine test so far; however this is giving me undefined is not a constructor error -

```
it( 'expect something...', () => {
        spyOn( Leaflet, 'tileLayer' );
        expect( Leaflet.tileLayer ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    } );
```

What's likely happening is I am missing the concept entirely and going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would move the code from constructor to OnInit. constructor called once and onInit for multiple instances.

   ```
   ngOnInit(): void {
   this.map = Leaflet
     .map("map")
     .locate({
       enableHighAccuracy: true,
       setView: true,
       maxZoom: 16
     });
   Leaflet.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
     .addTo(this.map);
   ```

   }
2. You need to make sure that tileLayer is actually called (not just stubbed) because you chain it with addTo function. So callThrough should be used.

so something like that should work:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
      spy = spyOn(Leaflet, 'tileLayer').and.callThrough();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LeafletComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('expect something...', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! This has really helped me - Just need that last 5/10% to understand it all